# How do I import InvalidURL exception in praw for python?

Tags: python, praw

I'm not able to import InvalidURL exception like this:

```
from praw.exceptions import ClientException, InvalidURL
```

ClientException exists, but InvalidURL doesn't for some reason.

The exception is there in the [documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/exceptions.html) and [github repo](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/exceptions.py).

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version, `pip install -U praw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`git blame`](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blame/5bd88f7ce5a2d6c8af909b9fb7b0e3daeb8c2f0a/praw/exceptions.py#L198), the `InvalidURL` class was added to the codebase about 6 months ago. As @DeepSpace [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021989/how-do-i-import-invalidurl-exception-in-praw-for-python#comment111446720_63021989), upgrading `praw` to the latest release using `pip install -U praw` should do the trick. (Please note that `-U` is the same as `--upgrade`.)

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought of that, but didn't realize that I only had the newest version installed in my docker container, but not on my IDE